# 3D model - get 2d images by through model

Tags: 3d

Imagine I have 3D model which is very big for example a shopping complex and I am given a 3D model of a complex and I want bunch of 2D images of all sides of complex including the top view and complex side view and walkway inside the mall between the shops.

I also want to move inside the mall in lobby between two shops say target and walmart and have 2D images of that lobby also.

Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Is there any need for automation? If not, this is not really a programming question and you could simply render the images in a 3D modeling/rendering package. So you might want to clarify.

Comment: Sorry @Bart. I am not sure any software are available to do automatically. Rendering in 3ds max just brings bunch of images from current view of my 3D model and that also does not seem to be proper once. I am confused how to do

Comment: Could you provide some images of what you have and what you want to get in result, explaining where it fails? That would help to answer your question.

Comment: Hi NBibodi, I'm struggling with a similar problem. I want to convert high poly 3D models to low poly models probably by taking images and putting them on a plane as in billiboarding. Could you offer me advice for converting 3D models to low poly solutions..

Answer (score 0):

Google Sketchup has several ways to generate side or top views and it is also very manipulable. I have used it for similar projects. There are also a number of Autodesk programs that allow you to do similar things in a more professional interface.